# get value when the button is click on alist view

Tags: android

```
    public class CustomList extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

            private final Activity context;
            private final ArrayList<String> web;
         public CustomList(Activity context, ArrayList<String> web ) {
                super(context, R.layout.list_single,web);
                this.context = context;
                this.web = web;
         }

            @Override
            public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
                LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
                View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_single, null, true);
                EditText txtTitle = (EditText) rowView.findViewById(R.id.txt);
  Button btn=(Button)rowView.findViewById(R.id.btn);

                ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.img);
                txtTitle.setText(web.get(position));
        return rowView;
            }
        }

    public class MainActivity extends Activity {
        ListView list;
        ArrayList<String> web = new ArrayList<String>();
           @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            web.add("Dsfsaf");
            web.add("xcxc");
            web.add("Dsfsafxcxc");



            CustomList adapter = new CustomList(MainActivity.this, web);
            list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
            list.setAdapter(adapter);
          }
      }
```

In the above example I show list view including text view ,TextField and Button using Custom adapter.It works fine but i need to take the input text field value when the button is clicked

Comment: where is the button in your listview rows?

Comment: write button listener in getView

Answer (score 0):

Use [OnItemClickListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemClickListener.html) ! 
Implemented like this: `onItemClick (AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)`
Your 'view' parameter will be your row layout. then just get your edittext like this:

```
EditText txtTitle = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.txt);
```

And then your String by the usual way:

```
String yourString = txtTitle.getText().toString();
```